# How to delete queues and bridged queues

Tags: tibco

I would like to delete a list of queues, bridged queues and topics
what is the best practice ?

I see from documentation  we can simply    >> delete queueName

But should I also delete topic, bridged queues ? 
can I just delete the bridge ?
or should I delete all ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go in sequence first delete queues then delete topics. 
After this you can delete bridges.